# How does MS Identity SecurityStampValidator work with EF Core? dotnet 7 web app

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

In dotnet 7 web app: for **SecurityStampValidator**:

**What are the consequences of shortening the validation interval from 30 mins to 1 min?**

My concerns in doing this are: how often is the database hit? Is a cache used by efcore?

In program.cs

```
        builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o =>
 o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

versus

```
...TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

**For context:**
I am  updating the SecurityStamp for the user inorder to invalidate all browser sessions. Typically this is done on a password reset.

I call this method which has the effect of invalidating all login cookies for this user

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    CustomIdentityUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
    return Page();
}
```